# What happens in detail when casting 1Byte data into 4Byte

Tags: c++, c, casting

I'm trying to implement MD5 Algorithm according to RFC1321 in C/C++ and have some trouble with type conversion.

```
typedef unsigned int uint4;  // 32 Bit (4 Byte)
typedef unsigned char uint1; //  8 Bit (1 Byte)

// pseudocode
uint1 byte = {1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0}; // 0b10011110
uint4 t_uint4 = (uint4)byte;

uint4 = { ??? }

// maybe like this??
uint4 = { {1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0},{???},{???},{???} }
uint4 = { {???},{???},{???},{1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0} }
```

So what happens in detail when casting a 1Byte variable into a 4Byte variable, respectively a unsigned char into an unsigned int?

Comment: Read about "big endian" and "little endian".

Comment: this code won't compile. it's difficult to accurately understand what you're asking unless you provide code that is syntactically correct. I could make assumptions, but it's likely i'd be wrong about what you really want to know. It seems to me that you could be asking about either casting a byte to an int32 or reinterpreting a byte array as an integer. the results would be different.

Comment: Please replace the pseudo-code by compilable  code

Comment: I am not sure how much detail you are looking for but as far as bit by bit is concerned the least significant bit of the 4-Byte variable equals the 1-Byte variable while the 3 other bytes are all zero.

Comment: Do not use homebrew types. `stdint.h` is exactly meant to provide types with fixed size! Neither `char` nor `int` are guaranteed to have a specific bit-width.

Comment: There is no magic here. If `uint1` has the value 158, the `uint4` will also have the value 158. And the cast isn't really needed.

Comment: This is neither C nor C++. Either add code for one of the langauges, or remove the tags.

Comment: @RichardHodges The title says "casting", and there are no pointers in the pseudocode. It looks to me like the only "pseudo" part of the pseudocode is the indications of specific bit-values within bytes, which of course *can't* be represented directly in C/C++ code (er... sorry, yes, C++14 *does* support this, actually).

Comment: @DieterLücking In C, AFAIK, there's no direct way to represent the bits in a primitive, and the `0b#####` comment added by Jarod42 is only supported as a literal int representation in C++14.

Comment: @all as you can see here: [link]http://www.zedwood.com/article/cpp-md5-function in the MD5 class method decode there is used a cast:

Comment: @tbol ...why do you need to understand what happens at the *bit level* in order to re-implement that function? The point of a "high level" language such as C or C++ (with scare-quotes because these are pretty low-level languages) is to allow you to think and code at the *logical level* so that the compiler can take care of the bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the answer. Look at this little snippet:

```
typedef unsigned char uint1;    // 1 Byte ( 8 Bit)
typedef unsigned int uint4;     // 4 Byte (32 Bit)

uint1 test=10;
uint4 test2=(uint4)test;


cout << sizeof(uint1)*8 << " Bit-" << "Variable (test): ";

for (int i=0; i<sizeof(test)*8; i++) {
    if ((test << i) & 0x80)
        cout << 1;
    else
        cout << 0;
}
cout << endl;
cout << sizeof(uint4)*8 << " Bit-" << "Variable (test2): ";

for (int i=0; i<sizeof(test2)*8; i++) {
    if ((test << i) & 0x80000000)
        cout << 1;
    else
        cout << 0;
}
```

Output:

8 Bit-Variable (test): 00001010

32 Bit-Variable (test): 00000000 00000000 00000000 00001010

Comment: Writing some code to figure out the *actual behavior* is an awesome thing to do; props. But note that as pointed out in Matteo Italia, the actual underlying byte-order will be different depending on whether your system (or your marshaling infrastructure, or whatever) is big-endian or little-endian. (Typically this won't matter within a program; it's mostly important to consider when transferring data between programs, since data is typically transmitted one byte at a time, so ints and other data must be re-assembled from individual bytes.)

Comment: Also, note that if you're using a *signed* value, then, assuming your platform uses a 2's-complement representation, the padding values (the 3 bytes of 0's in your 32-bit value) will be 1's rather than 0's (to preserve the sign).

Answer (score 6):

The numeric value remains the same, so zeroes are added to the "logical" left. Where that happens in the underlying bytes that make up the 4-byte integer depends on the endianness of the platform.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness:

> So what happens [...] when casting [..] a unsigned char into an unsigned int?

C11 Standard (draft):

> **6.5.4 Cast Operators**
>
> [...]
>
> **Semantics**
>
> **5** Preceding an expression by a parenthesized type name converts the value of the expression to the named type. This construction is called a *cast*.

and

> **6.5.16.1 Simple assignment**
>
> [...]
>
> **Semantics**
>
> **2** In *simple assignment* (=), the value of the right operand is converted to the type of the
>   assignment expression and replaces the value stored in the object designated by the left
>   operand.

Comment: I don't really see how this answers the question.